# Refresh tableview not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in objective-c developpment, I need to find a way to refresh my tableview.

I have 2 `UIViewController`s, in the second one I insert data into my database and then I instantiate the first viewcontroller, it contains my tableview. I call a method that allows it to recover all of the data from the database, but when I use `[tableview reloadData]` nothing happens and `cellforrowatindexpath` isn't called.

econdviewcontroller: 
//I insert data in database and I instanciate class where my tableview is and call refresh method

```
first = [[FirstviewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstviewController" bundle:nil];

[first refreshList];
```

in Firstviewcontroller

```
-(void)refreshList{

   self.tableview= [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    tableview.delegate = self;

     NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     //I recover my data from data base

    IPADAGRIONEActivityList *arrayActivities = [IPADAGRIONEActivity findAll];

    if ([arrayActivities length] > 0)
    {
        for (IPADAGRIONEActivity * oneRec in arrayActivities)
        {
            [array addObject:oneRec];


        }
    }
    //activities is NSMutablearray that contains all my data
    self.activities = array;

    //I build dictionnary 
    [self buildObjectsDictionnary:activities

    NSLog(@"self.act%@",self.tableview);
    [array release];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

//numberofrowsinSection:

```
NSLog(@"rows%d",[[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:section]] count]);
return   [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:section]] ;
```

//numberOfSection:

```
NSLog(@"nbre of section%d",[objectsIndex count]);
return [objectsIndex count];}
```

//CellforRowatInddexPath: It dosen't access to this method

```
if (cell== nil) {
    cell = [[MHCActivityListCell alloc]init];
}

IPADAGRIONEActivity *activite;

cell.activityCategory.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [activite EMAIL]];
```

Comment: Show your code. Have you setup the connection to the data store (debugged) and the table delegate (debugged)?

Comment: Have you set tableView's delegate and datasource ?

Comment: What do the logs tell you about the number of rows and sections? And did you copy and paste the code into the question because you aren't actually returning the count for the number of rows. Any build warnings?

Comment: It gives me the right numbers, always >0

Comment: You should use addsubview for tableview

Comment: Self.view addsubview: tableview

Comment: I tried this : self.tableview= [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
   tableview.delegate=self;  [self.view addsubview : tableview] ; it didn't work

Comment: The problem I don't know why it didn't access to cellforrowatindexpath and viewforheader, but it has acess to numberofrows and numberofsection

Comment: If numberOfRows returns a value larger than 0 it should call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yes I don'y know what's the problem.I add that the secondview is modalviewcontroller, when I dismiss it Iam in the firstviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new tableview every time you call `-refreshList`. Remember that the tableView is a view, thus it needs to be added as a subview.

Once you understand that, you'll see that there is no reason to `alloc+init` a new instance of tableView every time you need it to refresh (and if, for any reason you need it, you need to add the tableView as a subview again). Basically, you need to make sure that the tableView that is being displayed is the same tableView that you're storing on your tableView property.

Comment: if I didn't insranciate tableview , if I log( self.tablebiew) it returns null value , and then [tableview reloaddata] has no effect

Comment: your tableView property is not a strong property then. You should remove the `autorelease` from it's initiation (or change the property to be strong/retain instead of weak/assign)

Comment: What I don't understand is why I don't have access to cellforrowatindex path , but I can access to numberofrows and numberofsection

Comment: They are delegate/datasource methods. I'm pretty sure that you have more than one tableView lying around

Comment: tell me please , the secondview is a modalview , it's correct to instanciate an object from the firstone and call the refresh method??

Comment: it always depends, but the short answer is yes (if you know what you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier by Bruno, you are instantiating your tableview every time and this is not the right approach. You need to refresh the same tableview which had the original data.

in your refresh list do something like this

```
-(void) refreshList
{
    // Get a reference to your viewcontroller's tableview

    UITableview *tableview = [self tableview];

    // Do your data manipulation

    [tableview reloadData];

}
```